# Crash on NSRangeException cannot remove observer for "heading"

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

Fabric/Crashlytics is logging the following crash (quite a few crashes so far), and I cannot figure out what is causing it:

```
Cannot remove an observer<VKMapAnnotationTrackingCameraController 0x155058110> for the key path "heading" from <MKUserLocation 0x153b60790> because it is not registered as an observer.
```

[image]

I assume this is coming from my `MKMapView` where I allow the user to set the map type to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`, but nowhere am I adding an observer.

Could this just be a MapKit bug? So far there have been 32 crashes in the last 30 days, which seems like a lot.

Comment: Did you search for this string in your code? (Perhaps a misplaced testing code?) also are you able to reproduce locally? What KVO do you have setup?

Comment: @AvnerBarr - No string in my code for that. I cannot reproduce it locally. I am not using KVO anywhere, that is why it is strange.

Comment: Are the crashes on a particular ios version ? Also Are they happening on a single app version ?

Comment: Looks like mainly 9.3.2. Happening on various app versions.

Comment: Any solutions yet? I'm facing the same issue lately

Comment: I'm also getting these reported on iOS 10

Comment: No, I still have not figured this out, and I keep getting reports about it.

Comment: Also seeing this on iOS 9 & 10

Comment: Also seeing in iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar crash with MapKit starting in OS 4.x. By 'similar' I mean it was related to KVO and observers but I don't remember the details.

The problem was: I had a class implenting the MKAnnotation protocol. But in this class I was accessing the coordinate property without using KVO (directly via the corresponding ivar):
_coordinate = ....
instead of
self.coordinate = ...

It seems that Mapkit is now (starting in OS 4) relying on KVO notification to monitor annotations position.

Comment: So you are saying I need to always refer to coordinate as `self.coordiante`?